# How do I sort a multidimensional hash array by a key maybe three levels in, in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, perl, sorting, hash

I am moving from Perl to PHP and am struggling to get my head around PHP sorting.

Here's what I have in Perl:

```
$log{'11111'}{'1'}{'20100102'}{'name'}='blah';
$log{'11111'}{'1'}{'20100101'}{'name'}='blah';
$log{'11111'}{'1'}{'20100103'}{'name'}='blah';

$cook='11111';

foreach $entry (sort {$log{$cook}{$a}{time} cmp $log{$cook}{$b}{time}} keys %{$log{$cook}}){
       ...
       }
```

Basically, I would have the same array structure in PHP but want to sort like I do above.

Comment: Oh my god. How can anybody read Perl?

Comment: @Coronatus There is good Perl and there is bad Perl just as there is good PHP and there is bad PHP. The code snippet above smells big time although it is hard to say it is definitely bad without knowing if the second level keys are all consecutive integers. If they are, what we have here is a simple failure to understand the appropriate data structure for the problem.

Comment: When you are sorting by a string deep within a data structure, it is best to apply a schwartzian transform http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform to pull the needed data closer to the surface.  the transform is equally valuable in Perl and PHP

Comment: question: what are you trying to do?  Have you mistyped your comparison?  your example?  $log{$cook}{$a}{time} doesn't make sense --> you don't have a key named time.  Your example only has one element at the $log{$cook} level, and it has 3 children.  There is no way the sort as currently written makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need the [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function.

You'll provide it with a compare callback function which would do the job of

```
{$log{$cook}{$a}{time} cmp $log{$cook}{$b}{time}}
```